Is there any verse in Scriptures or by any Acharya that says that Brahmanas are not Apaursheya?
I got this verse-
Sayanacharya in his commentary on Taitariya Samhita:
यद्यपि मंत्र ब्राह्मणात्मको वेद तथापि ब्राह्मणस्य मंत्र व्याख्यान स्वरुपत्वाद् मन्त्रा एवादौ समाम्नताः।
Though Mantra and Brahmana both are named Veda but because of having expatiation form of Brahmanas, Veda-Mantra is only eternal/original
I was wondering if there is some more verses like this and also if the translation of this verse is correct or not because I am not sure.
